# Samsung J5 and TAB4 refuse native debugging

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

*Using Android Studio 1.5.1 in a win7 ultimate sp1 and in a Mac mini 10.11.3 fully updated.*

I have a number of Samsung units for testing my app development incl JNI and this week my private Samsung Galaxy S4mini (Kitkat) died physically so I got a new Samsung Galaxy J5.

**However the J5 (lollipop) refuses to be debugged in native mode.** Does not matter the app, fails also with Hello-JNI.

*The J5 also have some odd java bugs like in a AlertDialog (with stacked linear layouts) linearLayout.addView(anotherLinearLayout); just crashes?? Also I have an odd JNI-bug, I like to debug. And both "bugs" works without crashing in my other devices my old S4mini and a TAB4 Kitkat and a TAB3 and S3mini.*

However **I found the TAB4 also refuses native debugging**. Both the TAB4 and the J5 works fine in (non-native) app-debugging. All other units debugs native no problem, just switching unit on the cable and run, works fine?

**Is there something missing in the J5 and TAB4 for making native debugging available?**

---

The debug error message is (I tried everything I could find):

```
Target device: samsung-sm_j500fn-0af60463
Installing APK: C:\Users\JB\AndroidStudioProjects\HelloJNI\app\build\outputs\apk\app-all-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.example.hellojni
Installing com.example.hellojni
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.hellojni"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.hellojni 
Success


Launching application: com.example.hellojni/com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.example.hellojni/com.example.hellojni.HelloJni" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.hellojni/.HelloJni }

Warning: debug info can be unavailable. Please close other application using ADB: Monitor, DDMS, Eclipse
Restart ADB integration and try again
Waiting for process: com.example.hellojni
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: run-as com.example.hellojni mkdir /data/data/com.example.hellojni/lldb
Error while launching debug server on device: com.android.tools.ndk.run.DebuggerContext$StartServerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: run-as is broken (please see http://b.android.com/187955 for details)
```